# How can I edit my search box

Tags: search, ajax

I want to customize my search box. I want it to auto complete as I type and not to be case sensitive. What should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

For the autocomplete search box, there is a fantastic module [Search Autocomplete](https://drupal.org/project/search_autocomplete) with a detailed installation guide, and also has functionality such as integrating Views and Transliteration modules (which will overcome special characters/capitilisation etc.)

There is also a [Patch](http://drupal.org/node/1782678) for an exposed filter that may be of some assistance (if you are using a custom search box that you have made) that will help with the "contains" or "contains any word" operator.